# SenTestingKit Not found In Xcode4

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode4, sentestingkit

When I tried to import `<SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>`, I get this error: SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h: No such file or directory.

I am using unit testing for the first. I am using xcode 4.2 with ios 5 sdk. But in my system I have two xcode version installed,4.2 and 3.2.5. Although i am using xcode 4.2 ,xcode3.2.5 is the default xcode in my system. Can any one help me with the unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SenTestingKit.framework is at :

/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework (OS X)

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOSX.X.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework (iOS)

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulatorX.X.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework (simulator)

for Xcode versions 4.3 and above prepend /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/ to the paths above

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but the frameworks path will be different for both xcodes. it might be in 3.2.5 frameworks path and when using 4.2, it may not find it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know in 3.2.5, but by default SenTestingKit is not in the Frameworks folder. Is it a custom framework?