# Added Tapku library in project giving Sen TestingKit error

Tags: iphone, error-handling

I have added in my project tapku calendar library, it is giving error

```
SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h file not found
```

I am not getting what this error is how to remove this. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939806/sentestingkit-not-found-in-xcode4) but doesn't help me, i didn't get it. Please guide for the above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 ya it is but please tell where is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `SenTestingKit.framework` to your project in your app's target > Summary > Linked Frameworks and libraries